# Get list of data from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please, I need to bring a list of data from a spreadsheet, to put it in a dropdown, however I can't get the following code to work.

Code:

```js
function cityDataValidation() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,7,sh.getMaxRows() - 1);
  const vsh = ss.getSheetByName("City");
  const vrg = vsh.getRange("A2:A100");
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(vrg).build();
  rg.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Este es Java. What I need is to replace the items A, B, C, D, E, with a list from a spreadsheet, where the sheet name is "List".

```js
<script>
  const apiCall = function (functionName, params = {}) {
  params = JSON.stringify(params);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((response) => resolve(JSON.parse(response)))
      .withFailureHandler((error) => reject(error))
      [functionName](params);
  });
};

const getFormData = (form) => {
  const data = {};
  Object.entries(form).forEach(([key, item]) => {
    data[key] = item.value;
  });
  return data
};

const form = {
 city: {
    label: "Lugar de trabajo",
    type: "select",
    value: "",
    items: [("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")],
    disabled: false,
    placeholder: "",
    rules: [(v) => !!v || "¡Esto es requerido!"],
  },
  }
  </script>
```

Este es el HTML

```html
<v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6" lg="2" xl="3">
  <my-input :item="form.city"></my-input>
</v-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function cityDataValidation() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,7,sh.getMaxRows() - 1);
  const vsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vrg = vsh.getRange("A2:A100");
  const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(vrg).build();
  rg.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Hello friend, it is not working for me, could you pass on my contact to help me please?

Comment: What does `pass on my contact to help me please?` mean?

Comment: Could you help me see where is the error please?

Here is the link to the spreadsheet 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eR90w9Jp_etyCBSM_zXvIffAoeGPSJXoszy0Jr2ig1o/edit#gid=742243727